# Duplicate COUNT when doing JOINS and CONDITIONS along with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables

**games**

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
| gameID | challengeID | player1_userID | player2_userID |
+--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
|      1 |           1 |              1 |              2 |
|      2 |           1 |              1 |              3 |
|      3 |           2 |              1 |              4 |
+--------+-------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**challenges**

```
+-------------+---------+
| challengeID | content |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 | one     |
|           2 | two     |
|           3 | three   |
+-------------+---------+
```

And I want the output to be as below. Basically, a user (say, userID = 1) wants all challenges' data along with the count of the games played against each challenge and also information on whether that challenge has been played by the requesting user.

**output (for userID = 1)**

```
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| challengeID | content | n_games | played_by_requestor |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+
|           1 | one     |       2 | TRUE                |
|           2 | two     |       1 | TRUE                |
|           3 | three   |       0 | FALSE               |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

This appeared to be deceptively simple, but I've been trying it for the past 4 hours (it is 1:35am now) and the best I could get to was the code below.

```
SET @myID = 1;
SELECT
    COUNT(g1.challengeID) as n_games,
    CASE
        WHEN g.gameID IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
    END AS played_by_requestor,
    c.*
FROM challenges c
LEFT JOIN games g
    ON  c.challengeID = g.challengeID AND 
        (player1_userID = @myID or player2_userID = @myID)
LEFT JOIN games g1
    ON c.challengeID = g1.challengeID
GROUP BY c.challengeID;
```

But it gives the wrong result. For requestor userID = 1, this code gives n_games = 4 for challengeID = 1 and also n_games = 1 for challengeID = 2.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d232d/1)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you are joining to `games` a second time. This is a recipe for duplicate records.

Comment: Once to get `n_games` and the second time to get `played_by_requestor`

Comment: You can get both statistics from a single join. The join you have doesn't do what you want anyway. Instead, ask in your CASE expression whether @myID is either one of the players for the challenge, and remove that logic from the first LEFT JOIN.

Comment: `not (sum(@myID in(player1_userID,player2_userID)) is null) played_by_requestor`

Comment: @siride - "The join you have doesn't do what you want anyway" - not sure about that. But without two joins, it is just not working.

Comment: @KayaToast: with the second join, you are essentially cross-joining the games. Every game within a challenge is paired with every other game in that challenge. This generates duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got it to work !

```
SET @myID = 3;
SELECT  
    COUNT(g.challengeID) AS n_games, 
    CASE 
        WHEN uC.p_challengeID IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
    END AS played_by_requestor, 
    c.*
FROM challenges c
LEFT JOIN games g
    ON (c.challengeID = g.challengeID)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT g1.challengeID AS p_challengeID
    FROM games g1
    WHERE (player1_userID = @myID OR player2_userID = @myID)
    GROUP BY g1.challengeID) uC
ON c.challengeID = uC.p_challengeID
GROUP BY c.challengeID;
```

If there is a more elegant solution (e.g. without using two joins on `games` table), I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: @splash58 in your sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d232d/2 ,  the `played_by_requestor` is 1 for both challenges, for @myID =4 too, which is incorrect.

Comment: The `not(sum())` business is suspect. I'd do something simpler, like `MAX(IF(@MyID IN(g.player1_UserID, g.player2_UserID), 1, 0))`.

Comment: @KayaToast: look at the data. Player ID 1 is in all of the games in spash58's example. For the data provided, it's correct.

Comment: Seems to work nicely. Please elaborate what does `MAX(@MyID IN(g1.player1_UserID, g1.player2_UserID))` do ?

Comment: it's usual agregate function. `in`,  if @MyID = g1.player1_UserID  or @MyID = g1.player2_UserID, returns true or false. Mysql casts it to 1 or 0 when used in max function. So, max will be `null` if no records, `0` if no proper record, or positive number which means true